# Launching a lightbox from a count function

Tags: javascript, lightbox

I have fairly limited experience with JavaScript, more copy/edit that create really.

Building a competition using Beej Jorgensen's HTML5 canvas scratcher. User needs to scratch X amount of scratchers and if 3 winning symbols are found the entry form needs to be loaded.

I have gotten the count and the trigger working fine with timed location function. after 1.25 seconds the page loads with the entry form, there was mention of having this form in a lightbox but that decision has not been finalized yet.

This is what works, easy enough.

```
function countDiamonds(count) {
    if (count==3) {
        setTimeout(function() { location = 'congrats.php' }, 1250);
    }
}
```

How would I trigger a lightbox without the user having to click on some link, so within the above function replacing "setTimeout..." with a lightbox trigger/call.

Comment: could you add the link of lightbox that you're using..

Comment: @sudhir
Been through 3 so far today, the most promising was http://www.webmasters.am/blog/how-to-call-lightbox-from-javascript/javascript/2009/10/